# Как сделать, чтобы текст выводился в одну строчку через For Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, время, for

```
import time

string1 = input("Please enter the line: ")
string2 = string1.split()

delay = input("Please enter the delay: ")

for i in string2:
    print(i, end = ' ')
    time.sleep(int(delay))
```

Необходимо, чтобы одно слово выводилось, скажем, каждую секунду в 1 строчку. Проблема: когда введено всё необходимое, то программа работает некорректно, а именно, при условии, что введено 3 слова, текст появится сразу же через 3 секунды, вместо появления по одному слову, как исправить программу?

Comment: Немного не понял вопроса. Взял ваш код, ввёл три слова в строку, все работает нормально. Скажите, пожалуйста, какой тест вы запускаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) поддерживает параметр `flush`. Вам нужно добавить `flush=True` чтобы получить нужный эффект:

```
import time


string1 = input("Please enter the line: ")
string2 = string1.split()

delay = input("Please enter the delay: ")

for i in string2:
    print(i, end=' ', flush=True)
    time.sleep(int(delay))
print()
```

Объяснение простое: для скорости вывод накапливается в строчном буфере пока вы не завершите строку переводом строки (что `print` и делает если не пользоваться `end=' '`). Когда строка переведена, накопленные данные выводятся. Это увеличивает скорость работы вывода в большинстве случаев. Но и иногда мешает, тогда с помощью `flush=True` вы отключаете строчный буфер и данные выводятся немедленно.

Comment: Спасибо человек! Программа работает правильно и без ошибок.